# Semi-automatic layout algorithms for a mind map

Tags: algorithms, graphs, trees, graphics, graph-drawing

There're some existing tree layout algorithms such as [Tidier Drawings of Trees](http://emr.cs.iit.edu/~reingold/tidier-drawings.pdf) and [Drawing Non-layered Tidy Trees in Linear Time](http://oai.cwi.nl/oai/asset/21856/21856B.pdf). I call them as automatic layout algorithms since positions of nodes are determined entirely by the algorithm instead of the user.

Now I need an algorithm that allows positions of some nodes to be affected by the user (e.g. after node being dragged to another position) while calculate positions of other nodes.